# How to force my csv values to get in one column?

Tags: angular, csv, papaparse

I'm using [ngx-papaparse](https://github.com/alberthaff/ngx-papaparse) to convert an array into a CSV file.
But when I download my CSV file and open it with Excel my values are not in the right columns.

**Here is my  function:**

```js
downloadFile() {
  const tableKpi = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.kpi.indicators.length; i++) {
    tableKpi.push(this.kpi.indicators[i].values);
  }
  const blob = new Blob([this.papa.unparse(tableKpi)], {type: 'text/csv' });
  saveAs(blob, 'myFile.csv');
}
```

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIFEZ.png)

[What I expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeBBr.png)

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "not in the good column"? What is the expected and what is the actual behaviour?

Comment: @sevic Thanks for replying, here are some image

Comment: Did you tell excel what the desired delimiter is?

Comment: @S.Stumm I guess no, where should I put that ?

Comment: Select your data and then switch to the Data tab and press text to column. Select the seperation option and select comma as delimiter.

Comment: @S.Stumm I think the problem comes from the unparse function, I need an option but i can't find the right one for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, the format of the CSV file depends on your Excel language. Not every languages will parse the file the same way.
So I just needed to change my Excel language to English, hope it helps.